# FQL query to fetch all feeds by page name

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Hie

Can someone please tell me how to fetch all the feeds of a facebook page say "cocacola" using FQL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one query something like:

```
SELECT post_id,message 
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id IN (
    SELECT page_id 
    FROM page 
    WHERE name='coca-cola'
) LIMIT 5
```

**BUT** it's ***not*** recommended searching by name, since it may return more than one page. If you know the `page_id` use it directly. If you are a fan of the page try querying the `page_fan` table first.

Comment: This does not seems to giving me all the newsfeeds. Any idea how to fix it for that?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use graph:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed
```

[edit]

You could try with 2 query-es, one for getting page id and second for getting stream.
You can even try to combine them using [fql.multiquery](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/) like this:

```
"query1":"SELECT page_id FROM page WHERE name='cocacola'"
"query2":"SELECT message FROM page WHERE source_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #query1)"
```

Comment: Well we have some limitations with that. So i need a FQL way. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT post_id,message 
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id IN (
    SELECT page_id 
    FROM page 
    WHERE name='coca-cola'
) and actor_id IN (
    SELECT page_id 
    FROM page 
    WHERE name='coca-cola'
)
```